# Shor's algorithm for elliptic curve discrete logarithm problem

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm, quantum-cryptography, shors-algorithm

Could someone write Shor's algorithm for solving the discrete logarithm problem and how it could apply to elliptic curves in a few, easy to understand steps? I have a basic understanding of quantum computing, but not enough to understand his paper.

Answer (score 6):

Could one adapt Shor's algorithm to solve the DLP?  Yes: [Shor's original paper](https://doi.org/10.1137/S0036144598347011) ([arXiv preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9508027)) explains how, in §6 on p. 321.

Could one adapt Shor's algorithm to solve the ECDLP?  Yes.  Researchers at Microsoft recently [published estimates](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.06752) for how big a quantum computer you would need to do so.  (Spoiler: Smaller than RSA at comparable classical security levels.)

Could one write down how it works in a few easy-to-understand steps?  Maybe, but that's above my pay grade at the moment if you find those two papers to obscure!  You might start with [Scott Aaronson's article on Shor's algorithm](https://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=208), see if you can find the hidden subgroup problem hidden in the algorithm, and adapt it to the hidden subgroup problem in discrete logs.